# Software to view multiple VM screens

Tags: virtual-machine

I need to connect to multiple VMs at once. I remember using a software that manages all the connections & opens the VMs as tabs within the screen. I simply have to click on the tab  to open that VM.
Need suggestions for such VM manager, on Windows machine.

Comment: If you don't find it, consider virtual desktops, one for each VM and switch between those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. An ex-colleague's experience came handy.
'Terminals' is the software. This is exactly what i was looking for.

https://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Remote-Utils/Terminals.shtml